# Session disappear every post request action

Tags: php, mysql, session

So, I have a situation: 
I have a simple login action - you can login with your username and password and you go to module page after login.
But, on post request like add new article or edit new article how can you make your session disappear and it's OK if it get's a request.
I don't know why this won't work? I've set up a live session time / timeout and the session registers. Someone please help me.

Localhost :
mysqlnd 5.0.10
PHP Version 5.3.27

Cpanel : 
MySQL = 5.5.34-MariaDB 
PHP = PHP Version 5.3.27

header.php

```
session_start();
```

check.php

```
if(empty($_SESSION['id'])) redirect('login.php')
```

login.php

form with method post and if submit check user data if exist $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['id']

addnewpost.php

form with method post and if submit return data to sql (but its dont work because my session disappear and i redirect to login php)

Comment: Do you have `session_start` in your code?

Comment: yes sir, session_start include in my header

Comment: In that case, can you add some code to your question, enough that we're going to be able to reproduce the problem?

Comment: done any basic debugging, like checking `session_id()` values in every page? If you get different IDs, then you're getting different unrelated sessions.